# iOS TableView and prototypecell constraints not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, tableview, tablecell

I have a tableView with a prototypeCell.

I have added constraints to make the tableView take up the whole view:

[image]

I've added a "grey area" to the bottom of my prototypecell that take up 100% of the width.

However when i run the app there is a large area above the first tableCell, and the grey-area doesnt have 100% width:

[image]

What have I done wrong? Constraint issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should uncheck `Constrain to margins` and may be adjust your constraint's values to make your grey view full width.

Regarding white space on top - looks like it's something wrong with your tableView settings, not cells

Comment: Still same issue, it seems that the tableView start where the prototypecell ends in storyboard, is it suppose to behave like that?

Comment: Of course no, check your tableView constraints, layout settings, header view settings? Hard to say without code or/and tableView constraints.

Comment: regarding side constraints for cell - again, uncheck constrain to margins and set constraints values to 0 after that